# If $f'(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{|f(x) - [f(x_0)+L(x-x_0)]|}{|x-x_0|} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

In this exercise we are asked to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ with $f'(x_0) = L$ iff
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{|f(x) - [f(x_0)+L(x-x_0)]|}{|x-x_0|} = 0.$$ In my proof sketches, I did
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{|f(x) - f(x_0)|}{|x-x_0|} - \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{L(x-x_0)}{|x-x_0|} = L-L = 0.$$ But looking back, I'm pretty sure this isn't allowed with the absolute values. Any hints on other methods I should proceed, or how to fix the absolute value problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What you've written only makes some sense when $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, but, as you've pointed out even then you have absolute value troubles. Isn't this the actual *definition* of differentiability in higher dimensions? Perhaps you need to distribute the negative sign. Please give the context. Is $L$ a real number or a linear map? And you mean to have $f'(x_0)$ in the title.

Comment: You're right. This is in $\mathbb{R}$ and $L \in \mathbb{R}$ as well, and is designed to prepare us for the definition of differentiability in higher dimensions. This sketch was written really quickly and I just noticed the absolute value problems.

Comment: Any hints on how I should proceed? I wasn't sure exactly what approach to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: $$\dfrac{|f(x)-[f(x_0)+L(x-x_0)]|}{|x-x_0|} = \left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)-L(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}\right| = \left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-L\right|.$$

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.

Comment: Good. Just don't make the mistake in the multivariable setting of thinking you can separate out the $L(x-x_0)/\|x-x_0\|$. That will almost never have a limit.

Comment: Ah. I see. I'll finish this using the definition of a limit! Thank you so much :))